# What will the output voltage will look like if we have non sinusoidal AC paired with capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, diodes, rectifier, full-bridge

I am currently studying for exam and a lot of questions are popping up in my head.

What will Uout of a full wave bridge rectifier with a capacitor look like?

I am talking about square, trapezoidal, and triangular type of AC wave. I do not need any calculations only, how it will look so I can imagine it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capacitor will charge up to the peak voltage of the input waveform so, if the peak voltages of each waveform are the same then, the DC output will be the same. This is an unloaded capacitor scenario. With a resistive load across the capacitor, the output voltage will discharge a little between input voltage peaks but recharge to the original peak value when the input voltage returns to maximum voltage.

With a load on the capacitor there will also be a slight peak voltage reduction due to the diodes in the bridge rectifier having a small forward voltage drop when conducting.

Example of a trapezoidal input waveform at 50 Hz: -

[image]

With an open circuit load resistor, the peak voltage on the capacitor would be closer to about 9.8 volts rather than the 8.5 volts under load.

Triangle input waveform: -

[image]

Again, peak capacitor voltage will be about 8.5 volts with the load resistor connected.

Sinewave input: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer! So if I have triangular wave then the capacitor will load to the peak of the triangle wave, right?

Comment: The unloaded capacitor will charge to the peak of any waveform within reason.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

With a sine wave input, the rising edge will follow the peak sine voltage above the last DC level.  The trailing edge will follow dV/dt=Ic/C = RC.

The current wave will be a sawtooth narrow pulse ramping down to 0 at voltage peak.

The frequency will be 2f for a full bridge and 1f for a half-bridge.

The current average thru a diode pair and cap being a sawtooth pulse or a ramp down pulse = 1/3 of the peak from trig. Since the average current in must equal the average current out to Vdc avg/R but the duty cycle for current is the same for voltage thus the duty cycle of the pulse is about the same as the % ratio of ripple voltage.

- since the pulse voltage follows the peak sine shape, the rise time is not so sharp and more like a smooth trapezoid, but at extreme loads the pulse limited by diode resistance and/or transformer+cap ESR, takes shape more a a narrow square pulse with low ripple voltage.

Then the peak diode current becomes 3x / % ripple voltage, and limited by the diode's resistance at that peak current and rise in Vf of the diode then moving towards 1/%Vp ripple at high current with low ripple voltage as a more squarish pulse.